# How to find out which public key is actually in use and remove deprecated ones (gpg)?

Tags: gpg, key-authentication

I'm on Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon.

I have a minor problem with identifying the actual up-to-date GPG public key used by `apt-get` with **Spotify** music application.

I would like to **remove the old - deprecated public keys**.

[image: Spotify - redundant public keys]

I would like to do all this from CLI, if possible.

I'm unsure where to start, could anyone navigate me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List `apt` keys as `root` with `spotify` string:

```
# apt-key list 2>&1 | grep -i spotify -B 2
```

Remove, but the newest key with:

```
# apt-key del <keyid>
```

---

Example output in my case:

```
pub   rsa4096 2018-05-23 [SC] [expires: 2019-08-16]
      931F F8E7 9F08 7613 4EDD  BDCC A87F F9DF 48BF 1C90
uid           [ unknown] Spotify Public Repository Signing Key <tux@spotify.com>
--
uid           [ unknown] Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/spotify-2017-07-25-341D9410.gpg
--
pub   rsa4096 2017-07-25 [SC] [expired: 2018-07-25]
      0DF7 31E4 5CE2 4F27 EEEB  1450 EFDC 8610 341D 9410
uid           [ expired] Spotify Public Repository Signing Key <tux@spotify.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/spotify-2018-05-23-48BF1C90.gpg
--
pub   rsa4096 2018-05-23 [SC] [expires: 2019-08-16]
      931F F8E7 9F08 7613 4EDD  BDCC A87F F9DF 48BF 1C90
uid           [ unknown] Spotify Public Repository Signing Key <tux@spotify.com>
```

---

Tip: You can use fingerprint to delete the key:

```
# apt-key del "0DF7 31E4 5CE2 4F27 EEEB  1450 EFDC 8610 341D 9410"
```

Answer (score 1):

To list all the keys which are used to sign the repositories you care about, you should ask GnuPG. Start by clearning all the  `Release` files from the cache (to eliminate stale files):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*_{InRelease,Release,Release.gpg}
```

Then update them:

```
sudo apt update
```

Finally, extract the keys used to sign them:

```
(for file in /var/lib/apt/lists/*_InRelease; do gpg --verify $file; done; for file in /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Release.gpg; do gpg --verify $file ${file%.gpg}; done) |& grep "using .* key" | sort -u
```

and compare that list with the output of

```
apt-key list
```

to determine which keys are unnecessary.